# How to use wildcard to get ftp files on kettle spoon

Tags: ftp, wildcard, pentaho, kettle

I have a job using get ftp files, i am using this wildcard to fetch all the xml.zip files
    .*.zip

Works ok, but downloads all the files. I tried a wildcard to download only files with this pattern: .outsideXXXXXX.xml.zip (with no success).

```
 .outside\*.zip
```

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i found the solution:

```
.outside.*\.zip
```

FYI: pentaho pdi regexp are based on  java.util.regex package. The exact syntax for creating regular expressions is defined in the java.util.regex.Pattern javadoc.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 1):

Notice a difference between `outside*\\.zip` (correct) and `.outside\\*.zip` (incorrect)?

You need to escape `"."`, NOT the `"*"`

Comment: Don't know what is a significance of "spoon" in your title. I am more familiar with classic ftp. In any case if your server is accepting regex (.*\.zip looks like regex to me) you can give that a try:
`outside.*\.zip`

Comment: spoon is the data integration tool that is being used from Pentaho.  Also called PDI.